# Elasticsearch Switch between previous/next record from search result

Tags: elasticsearch

I am getting the results based on various filters in the Elasticsearch which also includes pagination.

Now I need to navigate between previous and next record from that search results, when we open a record of the search results.

Is there a way to achieve this through Elasticsearch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the *from* and *size* parameters of the [Search API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-from-size.html).

```
GET /_search
{
   "from" : 0, "size" : 10,
   "query" : {
       "term" : { "user" : "kimchy" }
    }
}
```

or

```
GET /_search?from=0&size=10
{
   "query" : {
       "term" : { "user" : "kimchy" }
    }
}
```

Note the default value for size is 10.